# What is that green rectangle next to altitude readout on Boeing aircraft?

Tags: boeing-777, altimeter, display

[image: B777 Altimeter]

Does anyone know what this green rectangle represents? It's from a Boeing 777 PFD. I can't find answers anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It indicates that the altitude is below 10,000 ft.**

My Boeing 777 FCOM shows the same rectangle in the PFD description, but does not mention any details about it.

However, the Boeing 747 FCOM includes more details:

> [image: Altitude Indications]
>
> **6 Ten Thousand Digit Display**
>
> Cross hatch displays when altitude is below 10,000 feet.

<sup>(Boeing 747-400 FCOM 10.10.28 - Flight Instruments, Displays - Controls and Indicators)</sup>

Comment: @J... I think it's more that 10,000ft is a magic number for "are we higher or lower than those mountaintops" reasons

Comment: @JackDeeth I very, very much doubt that... there are hundreds of mountains above 10,000' all over the world (and similarly, many huge regions where far lower altitudes are safe). The idea of 10,000' being any kind of safe-altitude rule of thumb is ridiculous.

Comment: @J... and there also being space on the display with the 1st digit being a 0 / not present!

Comment: @Tim I guess that is the primary function - to avoid ambiguity.  A black space might allow 3200 to be confused with 32000, and 03200 is just hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

This is a crosshatch marking to show the altitude is below 10,000 feet.  See [What is the meaning of the crosshatch marking on altimeters?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23881/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-crosshatch-marking-on-altimeters)

Comment: Any idea why it's green rather than white?

Comment: @JackDeeth My guess is because a digit in that position (above 10,000') would be white, so the green crosshatch reduces the chance of it being mistaken for a digit.